# Развертывание приложение на удаленном Glassfish заканчивается ошибкой TimeoutException

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish, развертывание, payara

Перекопал весь Интернет, но не помогает.

Выдает ошибку:

`java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

nucleus-grizzly-all.jar заменил.

Отлично работало до определенного момента. Ребутнулся сервер, и всё рухнуло. Использую Ubuntu Payara 4.1.1.154. Пробовал откатить сервер до 4.1.153, ничего не изменилось.

Спасайте, клиент рвет и мечет.

Наверное необходимо отметить, что среда разработки NetBeans8.1.(Windows10). И очевидно проблема в этом. Деплой на прямую, из админ панели прошел удачно. Буду пока пробовать разработку на IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Может поможет [TimeoutException on remote Glassfish v4.1 deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27999519/4295626)

Comment: Поправил пост. Менял. не помогает.